# SSRS IIF Statement not working properly when passing one or more of the values from parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have SSRS report parameter name "Status" which contains Passed and Failed values. In the report I have one column called Name. I want to hide this column when Status = "Failed" and I want to show this column when Status = "Passed" or Status = "Passed,Failed".

```
=IIF(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Status.Value,","), "Failed"),True,False)
```

Above expression hide the Name column for when Status = "Passed,Failed".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this .. but with the join, you may not need the / ToString() bit

```
=IIF((JOIN(Parameters!Status.Value,",").ToString().Contains("Failed"),"True","False")
```

Alternative:

```
=IIf(InStr(JOIN(Parameters!Status.Value,",").ToString(),"Failed") > 0,"True","False")
```

Comment: It does not work when I select both Passed and Failed from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
=String.Join(",", Parameters!Status.Label).Contains("Failed")
```